# How to connect active directory records from drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

My question, Is that possible? Can we do that in drupal 7?. If it is possible can you suggest some modules or some sample sites in drupal 7 . I am planning to do my project in Drupal 7. Also I need to implement a intranet facility in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's definitely possible. You'll need the [LDAP module](http://drupal.org/project/ldap):

> The LDAP project allows you to use your organization's existing LDAP-enabled identity management service (such as Active Directory) for Drupal account provisioning.

There's some pretty extensive [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/997082) available, that's probably the best place to start.